# Не правильно выводит массив с данными через JSON?

Tags: javascript, php, json

Есть данные в текстовом файле, точней массив, такого вида:

```
[[0,\u0022\u042f \u0022],[0.2,\u0022\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u0442\u043e \u0022]]
```

Вывожу JSON массив вот так:

```
$text=file_get_contents($filename);

echo json_encode($text, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

И при получении этого массива есть ошибка. `json_encode` добавляет всем Unicode данным, которые в этом массиве, еще один символ `\\`, то есть вот так:

```
[[0,\\u0022\\u042f \\u0022],[0.2,\\u0022\\u043f\\u0440\\u043e\\u0441\\u0442\\u043e \\u0022]]
```

И при получении массива через JS - `JSON.parse()`, соответственно получается ошибка.

Может существует какой то обход этого добавления символа?

Comment: вы считали из файла строку (не массив). закодировали ее в json, получили экранированные слеши.

Comment: А для того что бы создать массив из данных из файла нужно просто использовать file(); а не file_get_contents(); ? И как быть дальше не подскажите?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете раскодировать строку и снова её передать.

```php
$Arr = '[[0,\u0022\u042f \u0022],[0.2,\u0022\u043f\u0440\u043e\u0441\u0442\u043e \u0022]]';

$Arr = str_replace('\u0022', '"', $Arr);
function unicode_escape_decode($str) {
    return html_entity_decode(
        preg_replace('~\\\u([a-zA-Z0-9]{4})~', '&#x$1;', $str), null, 'UTF-8'
    );
}
$Arr = unicode_escape_decode($Arr);

$bz = json_encode($Arr);

echo $bz;
```

Comment: Спасибо вам за отклик, в общем чего то теперь у меня вообще возвращает пустые значение в массиве...

Comment: @Денис Милюков Пустые значения где? В `php` или в `js`? Проверил в php - выдаёт корректное значение.

Comment: Да там и там... В пхп вот так: [[0, 0.25, [[0,\" \"],[0.02,\" \"],[0.09,\" \"],[0.11,\" \"]]]

Comment: А в JS скорее всего иза того что ваша функция экранирует данные двойными скобками. А я данные через JSON.parse беру как массив который уже обвернут в двойные скобки

Comment: И пустые они иза того что это и есть пустые данные просо я привел кусок массива из файла. И вот тут попался как раз с пустыми значениями

Comment: @Денис Милюков удалось разобраться?

Comment: Увы но нет, сейчас пробую разобраться с данными которые находятся в файле, как оказалось я получал строку из файла а не массив. (Выше человек навел меня на мою ошибку).

Comment: @Денис Милюков Указанная мною функция работает со строками. )
Попробуйте для начала скопировать мой ответ себе и запустить.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105036/discussion-between---and-denis640kb).

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Все получилось как надо!